# Puzzled about Fuseki's rule-based reasoner behavior

Tags: jena

We would like to use Fuseki in the following way:

- A rule-based reasoner configured with custom rules uses all named graphs and adds the results to the union graph.
- We can use SPARQL updates to load/update named graphs; this should trigger the rule-based reasoner to update the results in the union graph.
- We can use SPARQL queries against the union graph or named graphs.

It is unclear how to configure Fuseki to achieve the above. I tried a configuration in this SO question [How to load user-defined rules in a fuseki configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099070/how-to-load-user-defined-rules-in-a-fuseki-configuration), but it lacked adequate context.

I created a reproducible example with a README that explains what we've done and the questions that arise with the use of the Fuseki 4.9.0 API.

https://github.com/NicolasRouquette/fuseki-reasoning-example

The questions are here:

- https://github.com/NicolasRouquette/fuseki-reasoning-example#6-lets-run-some-queries
- https://github.com/NicolasRouquette/fuseki-reasoning-example#7-check-reasoner-entailments
- https://github.com/NicolasRouquette/fuseki-reasoning-example#8-testing-a-sparql-insert-update
- https://github.com/NicolasRouquette/fuseki-reasoning-example#9-testing-sparql-delete-update

I realize that we're far from having clarity on using the Fuseki API to achieve the above requirements. It is unclear to me whether it would be simpler to achieve these requirements using a Fuseki server configuration instead of using the API.

I am trying a different approach with a reproducible example using the Fuseki 4.9.0 API in this repository:

Comment: You may get an answer to this detailed question by writing to the users@jena.apache.org mailing list (see jena.apache.org/help_and_support/index.html for the list)

Comment: Thanks, I posted this question on the mailing list here: https://lists.apache.org/thread/zp6cz4npc87g7rf7y2d19z1hdvoyonyj